# ¿Cómo cargar imagen en mysql con Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Tengo un clientdataset de productos con un campo longblob en la base de datos MySQL.
En el formulario tengo un TDBImage conectado al DataSet. Y un OpenPictureDialog

Luego hago en un button:

````
var
  fs : TMemoryStream;
  imgJPG : TJpegImage;
begin
  if dlAbrirFoto.Execute then
  begin
    imgJPG := TJpegImage.create;
    fs := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      imgJPG.LoadFromFile(dlAbrirFoto.FileName);
      imgJPG.SaveToStream(fs);
      fs.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      try
        imgFoto.Picture.Assign(imgJPG);
        DataModule1.cdsproductos.Open;
        DataModule1.cdsproductos.Edit;
       DataModule1.cdsproductosImagen.LoadFromStream(fs);
         DataModule1.cdsproductos.Post;
      finally
        fs.free;
      end;
    except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Asegúrese de que la imagen seleccionada es de ' +
           ' tipo JPEG con formato correcto. ' + chr(13) + chr(13) +
           'El error concreto: ' + E.ClassName + ': ' +
           E.Message, mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      end;
    end;

  end;
end; ```

Pero cuando selecciono una imagen jpg me dice: Bitmap image is not valid. Pero no se qué me esta limitando.
````

Comment: ¿En qué línea salta la excepción que mencionas?

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es imgFoto?
¿Has añadido la unit Vcl.Imaging.jpeg o jpeg (dependiendo de la versión) al USES?